# Electron Icon appears blurry on Windows Desktop

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm not sure if this is the right place for my issue, but I'll give it a try.
I have created an app with Electron Forge. I designed an icon using Adobe Illustrator.
Following the recommendations on the Electron Forge website, I created an icon sized 256x256 pixels and then converted it to ICO format.

When I install the app on my desktop, the icon appears pixelated. I've tried resizing it to both smaller and larger pixel sizes, but the image remains pixelated upon installation.

Does anyone know why?